# How to schedule two processes if arrival time is same

Tags: process, operating-system

In a single CPU process scheduler, if two processes arrive at the same time in what order will they execute in case of **FCFS, SJF, Non preemptive priority and RR**?
Below information is given about processes:

```
  {
    "Name": "P1",
    "ArrivalTime": 0,
    "Brust": 10,
    "Priority": 3
  },
  {
    "Name": "P2",
    "ArrivalTime": 0,
    "Brust": 1,
    "Priority": 1
  },
  {
    "Name": "P3",
    "ArrivalTime": 0,
    "Brust": 2,
    "Priority": 3
  },
  {
    "Name": "P4",
    "ArrivalTime": 0,
    "Brust": 1,
    "Priority": 4
  },
  {
    "Name": "P5",
    "ArrivalTime": 0,
    "Brust": 5,
    "Priority": 2
  }
```

Comment: ...and what is your solution?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I don't have any. I am trying to search it through books and internet but every time I am getting examples of processes arrive at different time intervals. Can you answer my question if you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, 2 processes can not arrive at the exact same time. Arrival of a process means that the process (PCB) is added to a queue (any scheduling algorithm basically reads / writes / updates this queue and / or it's elements). Now, when you are modifying data structures like a queue, you will add one element at a time (in a multi-threaded environment, the processes which add elements to the queue would be synchronized). HTH.